# MailChimp/Mandrill webhook for message created/scheduled

Tags: api, mailchimp, mandrill

Is it possible to get MailChimp or Mandrill to notify a webhook URL whenever a message is either created for a list, or scheduled to be sent, along with the list and message IDs?

I have a client that wants to intercept messages from his campaign, add special data from his server, then send the resulting template through his connected Mandrill account. I'm trying to figure out how to implement the first step in this process.

Answer (score 0):

Although I know this is old someone may stumble into this thread, have you checked out the webhook information?

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/58303976-Message-Event-Webhook-format

It has an easy way to implement it inside the account. You just setup a URL to intercept and parse the incoming data. I recommend first saving the data then using a scheduled task to parse the job separately so you don't lose data (although mandrill will try 100x).

If the unique id is not enough for you with your events, and you are concerned about specific campaigns you can tag the emails upon send and they will have the tagged information with the incoming event.